# How to create a dictionary using 2 columns of csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am having a `csv` file, have its data in `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\isha\Desktop\SF head count report 7 mar 2019.csv')
```

The data frame have more than 20 columns, but I need to create a dictionary by using only 2 columns from `dataframe`.

Comment: Generally you can use `df.set_index('your_key_column')['your_value_column'].to_dict()` assuming that `your_key_column` has unique values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the `usecols` parameter in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', usecols=['first_col','second_col'])
```

You can give it the indices or names of the columns you want and Pandas will store only these in your df.

To create a dictionary, you can call the df's builtin method `df.to_dict()`

By default the key will be your index, and the two columns the values. If you just want these 2 columns, one as key and one as value, then follow Chris A's advice:

```
df.set_index('your_key_column')['your_value_column'].to_dict()
```